# Key Value Pairs sending to Database for Submit Action

Tags: database

I have a Grid Which contains Access Details of a Users which is of multiple rows

-User Can take Retain Action \Delete Action against Each Record
-On click of Submit we need to send this AccessID and Action as a key value Pair to Database.

I Have a possible solution for this and i'm achieving this with Below method

1.Make an Xml string using StringBuilder Class and send that xml string as a parameter 
2.De-couping that using using Sql inbuilt function into a temporary table.

This approach is causing me Performance issues

Please suggest me if any one a alternative for my problem

Answer (score 0):

You should make a stored procedure with two parameters and call it.  No need to convert to xml and send to the database then convert back.  Keep it simple.

If you are doing it this way because you are directly calling the DB then you have a big injection security hole and you should use a stored procedure.